# need to empty a div but keep only a few div's inside the div but retain there jquery click functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which I need to empty excluding a couple of divs inside it, the problem is, I have got it to work but the div's lose there jquery click functionality.

I have a stage which will have items dragged on them but I need to be able to empty these items but retain the click buttons which are also on the stage and stored in a div called keep. 
I found this and it works but the things inside #keep still appear but they lose their jquery `.click()`.

```
var $stage = $('#stage'), $noRemove = $stage.find('#keep'); 
$stage.html($noRemove);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because they are being removed and then re-added.

You either have to remove the children. OR Rebind the click method afterwards.

So for example:

```
$noRemove.click(function(...){});
```

See the Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/r98dj/1/

Also, as a note. Make keep a class. Otherwise you'll end up with multiple divs with the same ID and this will cause you to fail W3C validation.